# Pasar variable a función anónima en query

Tags: php

Estoy teniendo un problema el cual no se como solucionar ya que en la documentación de Laravel 8 no hay un ejemplo el cual lo explique. Este es el fragmento de código el cual estoy trabajando.

```
  public function filtroMesa(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->id;

     //Obteniendo total de $ Gastado en cada pedido. 
     $prueba = DB::table('historico_mesa_pedidos')
     ->select ('historicoMesa_id', DB::raw('SUM(cantidad*precio) as totalMesa'))
     ->groupBy('historicoMesa_id');
     
    //Obteniendo las mesas junto con el total obtenido anteriormente y poniendo filtro seleccion a traves de ID en el where.
      $historicoMesa= DB::table('historico_mesas')
      ->joinSub($prueba, 'prueba', function($join){ 
         $join->on('historico_mesas.id', '=', 'prueba.historicoMesa_id')
              ->where('historico_mesas.mesa_id', '=', $id);
      })->get();
      dd($historicoMesa);
}
```

Voy a proceder explicar lo que quiero realizar. Esta función de **filtroMesa** recibe dentro de la request una ID la cual hace referencia a la id de una mesa *(es un sistema de restaurantes donde tengo de entidades: "mesas" y "pedidos", donde cada pedido se relaciona a la mesa)*

Luego:

```
//Obteniendo total de $ Gastado en cada pedido. 
 $prueba = DB::table('historico_mesa_pedidos')
 ->select ('historicoMesa_id', DB::raw('SUM(cantidad*precio) as totalMesa'))
 ->groupBy('historicoMesa_id');
```

Esta parte me relaciona los pedidos a las mesas correspondientes y me devuelve básicamente lo que gasto cada mesa en el pedido. Como se logra ver en la siguiente foto:

[image: Pedidos y su totalidad]

Ahora, la siguiente parte del codigo:

```
 //Obteniendo las mesas junto con el total obtenido anteriormente y poniendo filtro seleccion a travez de ID en el where.
      $historicoMesa= DB::table('historico_mesas')
      ->joinSub($prueba, 'prueba', function($join){ 
         $join->on('historico_mesas.id', '=', 'prueba.historicoMesa_id')
              ->where('historico_mesas.mesa_id', '=', $id);
      })->get();
      dd($historicoMesa);
```

Me tira el error que el parámetro **$id** no lo reconoce ( el $id sale desde la filtración de la request al principio).

Les voy a mostrar una foto hardcodeando el código poniendo como valor  2 donde iría el $id.
en la siguiente linea:

**`->where('historico_mesas.mesa_id', '=', 2);`**
Para mostrarles el resultado que quiero obtener.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden observar estoy obteniendo el resultado esperado, el problema que estoy teniendo es que no me reconoce el parámetro $id , ni siquiera poniendo  $request->id me lo acepta. Me dice que directamente no reconoce la variable,  estaría muy agradecido si alguien puede ayudarme. Espero haber sido bastante claro

Comment: Debes usar `function($join) use ($id) { ...` para poder acceder a la variable `$id` dentro de esa función.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aquí estás haciendo uso de [funciones anónimas](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (también conocidas como `closures`) y, acorde con la documentación, para poder acceder a variables del **scope padre**, debes hacer uso de `use`:

```
function () use () {}
```

Así que para tu caso:

```
$id = $request->id; <--- 
...

->joinSub($prueba, 'prueba', function($join){ 
     $join->on('historico_mesas.id', '=', 'prueba.historicoMesa_id')
          ->where('historico_mesas.mesa_id', '=', $id); <---- Fuera del scope
  })
```

Para poder acceder a dicha variable que está en el scope padre, debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
                                             vvvvvvvv
->joinSub($prueba, 'prueba', function($join) use ($id) { 
     $join->on('historico_mesas.id', '=', 'prueba.historicoMesa_id')
          ->where('historico_mesas.mesa_id', '=', $id);
  })
```

Comment: Claro, estás usando $id dentro de una función, en ese ámbito (scope) no existe la variable $id, la solución de Jonatan Lavado te debe de funcionar.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!! , suponía que era por el scope de la función pero no sabia como pasarle el parámetro. Ahora voy a poder tenerlo en cuenta para las próxima vez que me suceda algo similar.  Saludos !! Y desde ya muchísimas gracias :D